# Filling dependent drop downs with ajax, need to set selected value to person's db value

Tags: ajax

I have a form where the location fields use a dependent drop down set up, if you choose united states as your country the state dropdown will appear. The fields are populated through an ajax call when fired so it's not loading every single country, state or province, and city in the world on page load lol.

It all works great, however the problem I'm running into is how to set the default selected value from what's already saved. It has to prepopulate those values otherwise if the member doesn't change the location fields every time he edits his profile the location fields will be blank.

I sort of got around the issue by simply doing a query select and then adding the value on top of the ajax pulled values, but this is a really cheesy way to doing it and doesn't work very well.

I need to find a way to set the selected value from the ajax results. I'm sure it can be done by somehow defining the selected value in the code but I'm not exactly sure on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the selected value from db and use

```
<option selected value="<selected_value>">data</option>
```

while populating the data from ajax call..